# R:I want to skip lines but store a value

Tags: r

```
Sample File E:\CPC 091217\091217CPC2.C07
Model 3007
Sample #    1
Start Date  9/12/2017
tart Time   10:28:20
Sample Length   4:16:08
Averaging Interval (secs)   1
Title   
Instrument ID   3007-03160002 3.1
Instrument Errors   None
Mean    17193.2
Min 0
Max 128348
Std. Dev.   11582.1
Time    Concentration (#/cm³)
10:28:21    0
10:28:22    0
10:28:23    0
10:28:24    0
```

My file looks like this, I want to skip all rows from "Sample File" to "Std.Dev", I want the Time and Concentration be the header. But before that, I need to store the value of 03160002 (in Instrument ID) as A1, and use it in file name later on. What I wrote is following:

```
    cpcData <- read.csv(cpcFile, sep = ",", dec=".",
                row.names = NULL,header = TRUE,skip=8)
    A1<-cpcData[1,2]
    df = read.csv(cpcData, skip = 6, header = F)
```

A1 is fine, but the read.csv is no longer works for the rest of 6 rows. Because

```
    Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
      'file' must be a character string or connection
```

Expect output:

```
    Time    Concentration (#/cm³)
    10:28:21    0
    10:28:22    0
    10:28:23    0
    10:28:24    0
    (and A1==03160002)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't read that line with the number you want using `read.csv`, there are better `R` functions to read that.
Try this.

```
cpcFile <- "cpcFile.txt"
cpcData <- read.csv(cpcFile, skip = 14)
cpcData
#      Time Concentration....cm3.
#1 10:28:21                     0
#2 10:28:22                     0
#3 10:28:23                     0
#4 10:28:24                     0

txt <- scan(file = cpcFile, what = character(), nmax = 1L, skip = 8L, sep = "\n")
txt <- scan(what = character(), text = strsplit(txt, "-")[[1]][2], nmax = 1L)
txt
#[1] "03160002"
```

Note that when using `read.csv` you don't need to set `sep = ','`, `dec = '.'`, or `header = TRUE`. Those already are the defaults.
And *do* use `TRUE`, never `T`. Imagine that someone does this: `T <- FALSE`. This is perfectly legal and then what?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are giving `cpcData`, a data frame, as a filename.  I think your intent is to skip additional 6 lines to start reading the table part, but you cannot do that because the first `read.csv` call reads through all lines from 9th already.

What you can do is to read the same file again with `skip=14`, i.e.,

```
df <- read.csv(cpcFile, sep = ",", dec=".",
         row.names = NULL,header = TRUE,skip=14)
```

As a minor note, I think it should be `sep="\t"` not `sep=","`.  Your file does not look like comma separated.